# magento order observer simple query

Tags: php, magento

i want to add simple order observer , where i want few entries in my custom database:

order id , all products id , and referrer from which user comes (some id ),

where have i to write this observer, ..and what observer should i use for that ,

code :

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sampleobserversales>
                <class>SampleObserver_Sales_Model</class>
            </sampleobserversales>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <sampleobserver_sales_order_save_after_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>sampleobserversales/order_save_after_observer</class>
                        <method>activate</method>
                    </sampleobserver_sales_order_save_after_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Observer.php

```
class SampleObserver_Sales_Model_Order_Save_After_Observer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Applies the special price percentage discount
     * @param    Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return  FlexNewz_Sales_Order_Invoice_Pay_Observer
     */
    public function activate($observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();

        $sqlqury ="INSERT INTO `aaa` (`oid`) VALUES ('1')";
        $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $connection->query($sqlqury);

        //return $this;
    }
}
```

but i do not get any record inserted in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for my understand you tried to add something in your database when new order is created. Okay, so you tried to observe this event `sales_order_save_after`, and Event `sales_order_save_after` is a bit tricky.

The first time it's triggered Order is not yet commited to DB, and more to that - it actually doesn't have State and Status set yet. But anyway we can use this observer, and you used RAW sql query in your observer that's not good. You should create separate model for this.

I just add the observer here,

**local/PackageName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <PackageName_ModuleName>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </PackageName_ModuleName>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <modulename>
        <class>PackageName_ModuleName_Helper</class>
      </modulename>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <modulename>
        <class>PackageName_ModuleName_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>modulename_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </modulename>
    </models>
    <events>
      <sales_order_save_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <sales_order_save_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>modulename/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>mycustom</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </sales_order_save_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

And your Model, (observer)
**local/PackageName/ModuleName/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php
class PackageName_ModuleName_Model_Observer
{

            public function mycustom(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                //Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success', array('user'=>$user));
                //$user = $observer->getEvent()->getUser();
                //$user->doSomething();




  // Your custom stuff here goes ....
                    }
}
```

And finally define you module pool and enable,

**app/etc/modules/PackageName_ModuleName.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <PackageName_ModuleName>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </PackageName_ModuleName>
  </modules>
</config>
```

That's it. If you have any doubt, please comment here..

Comment: does sales_order_save_after gives completed order or not, ie correct order it that i sucessfull order ?.

Comment: yes, It will work. In your case you can use it, in addition it actually doesn't have status of the order. That's what I was meant .

Answer (score 0):

first check this part `sampleobserversales/order_save_after_observer`, I mean whether you use correct module name `sampleobserversales` and that path.

If it's ok, and still doesn't work, try to rename `sales_order_save_after` into `sales_order_place_after`

**UPDATE:**

sometimes CamelCase can make problems. Try instead of `SampleObserver` to type `Sampleobserver` and of course you should change everywhere where is `SampleObserver` and the file name as well. You should avoid of CamelCase in magento when you create class.